# Annotation visibility toggle by clicking trace on legend

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

As the title implies, is there a way to make an annotation dissapear/appear by clicking on the corresponding trace in the legend of a plotly chart?

Suppose I have a scatterplot with a nonlinear trendline I added with `add_trace`. The trendline has an entry in the legend box and I want to display/hide the equation for the trendline when I toggle the trace on/off in the legend box.

The annotations have a `visible` property that can be accessed, and I read about the `layout.legend.itemclick` but it only covers the events of the affected trace, no option to include an object like an annotation.

Any way to do this?
Thank you beforehand.